# Return smaller values in a BST inorder

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement this method, "smaller" for a BST, that returns the values in the tree which are smaller than a given item, in order.

```
class BinarySearchTree:
    def __init__(self, root: Optional[Any]) -> None:
        if root is None:
            self._root = None
            self._left = None
            self._right = None
        else:
            self._root = root
            self._left = BinarySearchTree(None)
            self._right = BinarySearchTree(None)

    def is_empty(self) -> bool:
        return self._root is None

    def smaller(self, item: Any) -> List:
        if self.is_empty():
            return []
        else:
            return self._left.items() + [self._root] + self._right.items()
```

So far, the "smaller" method will return all of the values in the tree in order, but I'm not sure how to check if those values are smaller and than a given item, and to only return those in a list.

Answer (score 0):

Let's write pseudocode for `in-order-tree-walk` method which prints the keys of `BST` in sorted (in-order) order.

```
in-order-tree-walk(T, x)
    if (T != NULL) 
        in-order-tree-walk(T.left, x)
        print T's key
        in-order-tree-walk(T.right, x)
```

`smaller` method has exactly the same structure as `in-order-tree-walk` except that it's additional condition which makes it to print keys that are smaller. `smaller` method's pseudocode will look like

```
smaller(T, x)
    if (T != NULL) 
        smaller(T.left, x)
        if (T's key is less than x)
            print T's key
        smaller(T.right, x)
```

We're done. `smaller` method is now completed. Now let's look at your actual implementation.
Your code prints all keys of `BST` in sorted order because of the way you implemented it. You have the problem the following part:

```
def smaller(self, item: Any) -> List:
    if self.is_empty():
        return []
    else:
        return self._left.items() + [self._root] + self._right.items()
```

In `return self._left.items() + [self._root] + self._right.items()`, you don't check whether the `[self.root]` is less than `item's value` or not. You have to check that because you put restraint on printing the key of tree, but in implementation you didn't check it. Since I'm not qualified in Python, I can't complete this part, but I think you've get what the problem is with your code based on above explanations.

Comment: Yes, I understand that my code doesn't currently check compare, that is what I am asking for help with. How can I implement it?